# Ruby/Rails - Problem to build a method with request.fullpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a method in order to add a specific css class to my nav menu on current pages.

Here is my start: (in application_helper)

```
def menu_links(param)
 if request.fullpath == "#{param}_path"
   return "#{param}_path"
 end
end
```

in my app view:

```
<%= menu_links("help") %>
```

However, if I change request.fullpath == "#{param}_path" by request.fullpath == help_path, it works. don't know why.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the second case (`request.fullpath == help_path`), you use the `help_path` method, which expands to some URL (say `http://example.com/help`). In the first case, you just use a `"help_path"` string, which doesn't mean anything special to Rails. You probably need to use `eval`:

```
def menu_links(param)
  if request.fullpath == eval("#{param}_path")
    return eval("#{param}_path")
  end
end
```

Although it's not the best solution...

Comment: just make sure you sanitise that `param` arg if it has come from the user!